# javascript reduce

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array coming from the backend. It consists either of numbers or dashes '-'. 
I operate the `reduce` function on it.

I want to sum up all numbers in this array.
If the array only contains dashes I want to return a dash '-'.
If the array contains numbers I want to return the sum.

As far as I know the reduce function needs `current value`.

- When I use a dash as `current value` and the array has numbers I get returned `NaN`.
- When I use a 0 as current value I get returned `0`.

What is the easiest way to solve this problem?

```js
myReduce = function(a, b) {
    if (a !== '-' && b !== '-') {
      return Number(a) + Number(b)
    } else {
      return '-';
    }
}
    
arrayNumsAndDashes = [1, 2, 3, 4, '-', 5]
arrayNumsAndDashes = arrayNumsAndDashes.reduce(myReduce, 0)
console.log('arrayNumsAndDashes:' + arrayNumsAndDashes)

arrayNums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
arrayNums = arrayNums.reduce(myReduce, 0)
console.log('arrayNums:' + arrayNums)

arrayDashes = ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-']
arrayDashes = arrayDashes.reduce(myReduce, 0)
console.log('arrayDashes:' + arrayDashes)
```

Thanks for the efforts.

Comment: But you do know that your `a` and `b` **are not array elements** right? One of them is "next value"  and another one is "accumulated value"  whatever it is or "index" (cannot remember) https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Obiekty/Array/Reduce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signature for Array.reduce, according to MDN, is:

```
arr.reduce(callback[, initialValue])
```

If you pass in an initial value, it becomes the first a-value when running myReduce. It would be easiest to pass in '-' as the initial value, as I've done here:

```
myReduce = function(a, b) {
    if (b !== '-') {
      if (a === '-') return Number(b);
      else return Number(a) + Number(b);
    } else {
      return a;
    }
}

console.log([1, 2, 3].reduce(myReduce, '-'))    // 6
console.log(['-', 2, 3].reduce(myReduce, '-')) // 5
console.log(['-', '-'].reduce(myReduce, '-')) // '-'
```

And here is a perhaps easier to read version:

```
myReduce = function(a, b) {
  let aIsNumber = typeof a === 'number'; // or a !== '-' if you rather
  let bIsNumber = typeof b === 'number'; // or b !== '-' if you rather

  if (aIsNumber && bIsNumber) return a + b;
  return (aIsNumber && !bIsNumber) ? a : b;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Jordan Stubblefield for the answer. This works great!

Answer (score 0):

Check my answer. If it works for you

```js
//array = [1,2,"-", 3, 4, "-"];
array = ["-", "-"]

var result = array.filter(x => Number.parseFloat(x)).reduce((a,b) => a + b, null) ;

var result = result == null ? '-' : result;
  
console.log(result );
```

Comment: OP said he wanted to return a dash if there were only dashes in the array. Worth noting, too, that `Number.isInteger` will return false for decimal values. From OP's example as well it looks like the numbers could start as strings, and this reduce function would just concatenate them.

Answer (score 0):

If the *only* time you want a dash is when the array contains no numbers (only dashes), I'd filter the dashes first and return conditionally on array length:

```
const array = [/*filled with mysteries*/];

return array.filter(a => !isNaN(a)).reduce((a,b) => a + +b, null) || '-';
```

that takes all non-numbers out of the array and tries to reduce it with an initial value of `null`. If there's no numbers in the array to reduce (length zero), the result is `null`....which means there were only dashes in the array before filtering, so we can return a dash.